# Tomcat behavior for CLOSE_WAIT connections

Tags: java, tomcat, tcp, server

The acceptCount queue is maintained at OS level. Lets say we have a acceptCount queue of 10K.

Situation - The server is unable to process the request or is taking a long time due to one of the dependencies or network issue and during the time all the clients timeout. Eventually the queue has 10K CLOSE_WAIT connections. Now if the service is backup again and start processing. Would it clean up the CLOSE_WAIT connection queue? How will tomcat behave in such situation.

Answer (score 2):

> The `acceptCount` queue is maintained at OS level.

By this I assume you mean the listen backlog queue.

> Let's say we have an `acceptCount` queue of 10k.

There is no way to tell. You can *hint* to the operating system how long you would like it to be, but the operating system can adjust it both up and down, and there is no API to tell you what the actual length is.

> Eventually the queue has 10k CLOSE_WAIT connections.

No it doesn't. CLOSE_WAIT states are not queued anywhere, and the listen backlog queue has nothing to do with CLOSE_WAIT whatsoever.

> Would it clean up the CLOSE_WAIT queue?

There is no such queue to clean up.

If what you are really asking is would restarting the process clear all the *ports* in CLOSE_WAIT state, the answer is that *exiting* the process which held them would do that.

However so does letting Tomcat detect all the closed connections and close them itself. If you have lots of these, the real issue is why it isn't doing that automatically. It should.

If this is caused by one request being forwarded somewhere, it sounds like something is synchronized internally that shouldn't be synchronized, in your application.

Comment: By acceptCount, I was talking about the tomcat acceptCount parameter. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @User23890 Yup. Nothing to do with CLOSE_WAIT whatsoever.

Comment: By 10K CLOSE_WAIT connection queue, I meant the connection queue at OS. I think I confused it here. But listen backlog queue is what I am talking about. Isn't it the same thing as the acceptCount ?
Edit - Sorry then its the maxConnections parameter I am talking about

The thing that I wanted to understand is - What happens if your service has over thousand clients sending data and one of the service dependencies goes down. The server would pile up CLOSE_WAIT connection at service end. Isn't it? If it is true, how would they clean up?

Comment: @User23890 I repeat again. (1) The listen backlog has nothing to do with CLOSE_WAIT whatsoever. (2) There is no CLOSE_WAIT queue, and there is therefore no CLOSE_WAIT queue size. I don't understand why you think CLOSE_WAIT connections would 'pile up', either. They should all get closed as soon as Tomcat reads EOS on each one. Independently, unless there is a synchronization problem as I mentioned above. What is your *actual problem?*

Comment: Actual problem - We have web service which is processing ~1000 TPS. In certain situations, we notice when a service dependency goes bad, our service keeps on waiting on that dependency. Doesn't even responds to ping. The service never recovers from the situation even after the service dependency comes back unless we restart the service. During the same time, we have observed the number of established connections increases and after some time the CLOSE_WAIT connections on the host are noticed ~10K which remains there even for an hour unless the service is restarted.

Comment: So you need to use a timeout when talking to the upstream service, and look for an unnecessary synchronisation or sequentialization. It's an application problem. No amount of mucking around with Tomcat parameters is going fix it.

Comment: Thanks EJP for answering my queries. I got the problem and I agree that setting up a timeout is the right way. Now coming back to what I wanted to understand. First, Does the problem of CLOSE_WAIT sounds reasonable to you? The thing that is still unclear to me is why those connections don't close up eventually? Is that the expected behavior. I am not very clear in these concepts and don't expect for a full explanation here. Even an external link to a reading material would be fine.

Comment: One more time. You have a synchronization or sequentialization somewhere such that when your un-timed-out upstream service fails, all the threads that want to call it next are blocked, so they can't detect client disconnects, so they don't close their end, so the port goes into CLOSE_WAIT until they do. A timeout will fix part of it but you also need to look for the synchronization or sequentialization.

Answer (score 1):

a few tips about CLOSE_WAITS and reaching max connections/thread count,
(I had similar problems in WebLogic server, but these are general tips)

to release stuck threads due to network issues: (if allowed according to the business)

1. set timeout value to all remote calls (e.g. DB/ HTTP/ EJB/..)
2. check for Terminating/Killing long running threads (requests)

better check closely and get to the root-cause, before trying any workarounds.

CLOSE_WAITS should clear after heavy-load period is over in case this is the issue, but in case of stuck threads you might need a restart ASAP to solve the issue.